# Updated Failed - Green in folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We have the following message in TortoiseSVN.

Error retrieving REPORT: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Completed!

We wish to know how to solve the challenge.

Answer (score 1):

**Do you have the same error?**

Error retrieving REPORT: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

We have done the with following

$ sudo reboot

We also shutdown the local computer for while.

In addition, we use the local machine C drive.

Hope that will help you.